# selecting rows from database depending on number occurances using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have question regarding SQL. The psuedo code is as follows:

```
Select ids 
from table_1
where id exists for last seven days
```

In the table followinf entities are included.: ID, recieveddate, name

I am suppose to solve this query using SQL

Comment: Is this homework? Your title doesn't make sense - you talk about number of occurrences but then you're talking about restricting by a date range in your post.

Comment: @Derek: Actually it is you who are speaking about number *of* occurrences, while the OP is speaking about *number occurrences*. But to be honest, my first reading was same as yours.

Comment: What is the condition - 'id exists for ONE of last seven days' or 'id exists for EACH of last seven days'?

Comment: Adding to:@Devart's salient questions, does it have to be exactly once per day for each of the last seven days or can there be remainder? Please post table, constraints, sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about the syntax but I am going to adventure an answer after looking at [this documentation:](http://www.roseindia.net/sql/sqldate/mysql-date-subtract.shtml)

```
SELECT id from your_table where receiveddate>=Date_Sub(curdate(),interval 7 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id from table_1 where receiveddate <= date_sub(sysdate(),interval 7 DAY);
```